# Ошибка с переходом в другой тип при малых значениях numpy

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, типы-данных

Существует массив
`np.array([0.e+00, 0.e+00, 0.e+00, 1.e-50, 0.e+00])`.
Тип этого массива - `float`.
При умножении всего массива `b *= 30` на число, которые больше `19`, тип массива меняется на `object`. При `b = b * 30` тип все-равно меняется, хоть и без ошибки.

`b = np.zeros((5, 5))`

`b[1, 2] = 10 ** -50`

`b *= 10 ** 20`

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: `b = np.zeros((5, 5))    
b[1, 2] = 10 ** -50    
b *= 10 ** 20    
print(b)`

Comment: Укажите это в самом вопросе с помощью кнопки править и добавьте форматирование коду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можно:

```
b *= 10 ** (20 // 2)
b *= 10 ** (20 // 2)
```

И только в таком порядке. При `b *= (10 ** 20) // 2` выскакивает та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Если это дополнение к вопросу, то добавьте его в вопрос и удалите этот "ответ".

Comment: в новых версиях numpy (выше 1.7) правило одного типа стало обязательным. b - массив float. 10**20 - целое число. Если вы явно приведете виды: `b *= float(10**20)`, то ошибка исчезнет

Comment: `b *= 10. ** 20` или `b *= 10 ** 20.` ;)